# How to perform the onlick event even when the div is dragged?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a div:

```
<div 
    id="up" 
    onmousedown="mousedown('url(/scanToUserBox/img/cpt_subfunc_005_prev_p.png)', this)" 
    onclick="changePage('up')">
</div>
```

When I press it the onmousedown is triggered, but when I dragged away from the button and remove the click, the onclick event is not triggered. How can I trigger it without using onmouseout? (ondrag is not supported)

Comment: Use `document.onmouseup` instead of `element.onclick`.

Comment: @Teemu this won't fire after drag

Comment: @raam86 No? I've used it for years, and now you tell me that it's not working ; ). Please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cww55/6/). Though it's better to attach `document.mouseup` in the `mousedown` function than inline.

Comment: @Teemu my bad.I was checking this while you wrote you comment. Didn't check it well enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest adding listeners to the div. You can then use it like this:

```
  //get div  
var div = document.getElementById('up');
//Define a funcion where you do what you want on mouse release.
//Remove the listener after you are done.
function up() {
    //console.log("up")
    //do stuff
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', up);
}
div.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    //console.log("down");
    //Do stuff
    //Call mouseup when you are done with mouse down.
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', up);

})
```